# Repeat table by month from a date range using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have here some question regarding on the above subject.

I have a parameter which is **Start Date (01/01/2013)**
and **End Date (03/31/2013)**
and a **table** which displays the data.

Here is my question

Can I repeat the table by month?

so if my date range is **01/01/2013 to 03/31/2013**

I should have 3 tables for **January - February - March**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use a List control, grouped on Month Name or Month Number (or anything to designate a month), put a table within the List control to house your data for each month.

Comment: should I insert the table inside the list cell?

Comment: Yes.  If you've used grouping in a table before, you can expect it to behave about the same:  each "row" of the List will encapsulate the "detail" records for that rows grouping value.  So any objects you place in the list will have access to those - tables, charts, etc.  Sometimes you'll even find the need to use a list + a bunch of individual text boxes to achieve formatting that's impossible through normal tables.

Comment: but i have 5 tables with 1 datasource with different datasets? how will i be able to group this by month if i have multiple tables

Comment: Use a view to query your tables - combining all your datasets into one.